# Python string in pure hex form

Tags: python

```
>>> x = "\x55\x89\xe5\xb9\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb8\xc0\xa0\x04\x08\x31\xdb\x31\xd2\x8a\x1c\x08\x01\xda\x41\x83\xf9\x72\x75\xf5\x81\xfa\x71\x71\x00\x00\x74\x22\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb9\x7a\xa0\x04\x08\xba\x0a\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb9\x70\xa0\x04\x08\xba\x09\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\x5d\xc3"
>>> x
'U\x89\xe5\xb9\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb8\xc0\xa0\x04\x081\xdb1\xd2\x8a\x1c\x08\x01\xdaA\x83\xf9ru\xf5\x81\xfaqq\x00\x00t"\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb9z\xa0\x04\x08\xba\n\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb9p\xa0\x04\x08\xba\t\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80]\xc3'
```

Is there any way I can get the interpreter to print out x, exactly as I had input it? i.e. It should start with a `\x55` and not a `U`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get exactly what you want with the original value of `x`, write a display function:

```
>>> x = "\x55\x89\xe5\xb9\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb8\xc0\xa0\x04\x08\x31\xdb\x31\xd2\x8a\x1c\x08\x01\xda\x41\x83\xf9\x72\x75\xf5\x81\xfa\x71\x71\x00\x00\x74\x22\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb9\x7a\xa0\x04\x08\xba\x0a\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb9\x70\xa0\x04\x08\xba\x09\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\x5d\xc3"
>>> x
'U\x89\xe5\xb9\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb8\xc0\xa0\x04\x081\xdb1\xd2\x8a\x1c\x08\x01\xdaA\x83\xf9ru\xf5\x81\xfaqq\x00\x00t"\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb9z\xa0\x04\x08\xba\n\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb9p\xa0\x04\x08\xba\t\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80]\xc3'
>>> def display(x):
...     return "'\\x"+'\\x'.join(format(ord(n),'02x') for n in x)+"'"
... 
>>> print display(x)
'\x55\x89\xe5\xb9\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb8\xc0\xa0\x04\x08\x31\xdb\x31\xd2\x8a\x1c\x08\x01\xda\x41\x83\xf9\x72\x75\xf5\x81\xfa\x71\x71\x00\x00\x74\x22\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb9\x7a\xa0\x04\x08\xba\x0a\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb9\x70\xa0\x04\x08\xba\x09\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\x5d\xc3'
```

If you just want a hex dump, here is a standard library function with a slightly different format:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(x)
'5589e5b900000000b8c0a0040831db31d28a1c0801da4183f97275f581fa717100007422b804000000bb01000000b97aa00408ba0a000000cd80b801000000bb00000000cd80b804000000bb01000000b970a00408ba09000000cd80b801000000bb00000000cd805dc3'
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, add `r` before the quotes:

```
x = r"\x55\x89\xe5\xb9\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb8\xc0\xa0\x04\x08\x31\xdb\x31\xd2\x8a\x1c\x08\x01\xda\x41\x83\xf9\x72\x75\xf5\x81\xfa\x71\x71\x00\x00\x74\x22\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb9\x7a\xa0\x04\x08\xba\x0a\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb9\x70\xa0\x04\x08\xba\x09\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\x5d\xc3"
print x
```

**output**

```
\x55\x89\xe5\xb9\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb8\xc0\xa0\x04\x08\x31\xdb\x31\xd2\x8a\x1c\x08\x01\xda\x41\x83\xf9\x72\x75\xf5\x81\xfa\x71\x71\x00\x00\x74\x22\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb9\x7a\xa0\x04\x08\xba\x0a\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb9\x70\xa0\x04\x08\xba\x09\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\x5d\xc3
```

Comment: Of course, this is now a very different string. If you want the original back, you'll have to decode it with `x.decode('string-escape')`.